# Is the trinity in view at Revelation 7:17?

Tags: john, revelation, spirit, trinity, intertextuality

Revelation 7:17 (ESV):

> For **the Lamb** in the midst of the throne will be their shepherd, and he will guide them to **springs of living water**, and **God** will wipe away every tear from their eyes.”

Notice the similarity with John 7:37-39 (ESV):

> 37 On the last day of the feast, the great day, Jesus stood up and cried out, “If anyone thirsts, let him come to me and drink. 38 Whoever believes in me, as the Scripture has said, ‘Out of his heart will flow **rivers of living water**.’” 39 **Now this he said about the Spirit**, whom those who believed in him were to receive, for as yet the Spirit had not been given, because Jesus was not yet glorified.

So, in Rev 7:17 do we have in view the Son (*the Lamb*), the Father (*God*) and the Holy Spirit (*springs of living water*)?

Comment: Without a shadow of a doubt, I would agree and say, Yes. Up-voted +1 for your question and for your own answer, with which I agree. Permit me to suggest that you formulate a more substantial answer, and that you express yourself freely within that answer. I look forward to it.

Comment: For those who are wearing their Trinity-colored glasses, the Trinity is hinted at everywhere. For those, however, who lack that prejudice it is obvious that John was a strict monotheist: *[Jhn 17:3 NLT] (3) And this is the way to have eternal life--to know you, the only true God, and Jesus Christ, the one you sent to earth.*  Trinity is not taught by any biblical writer; monotheism is. *[Eph 4:6 NLT] (6) and one God and Father, who is over all and in all and living through all.*

Comment: @Ruminator No strict monotheist would make a statement like *the Word was God*,

Comment: @RevelationLad That is a translation issue. Perhaps, "God was the message." But no Trinitarian would have Jesus claim that [the way to have] everlasting life is to know his Father, the One True God!

Comment: @Ruminator The only reason the Trinitsrian issue exists is because of John 1. And you must also put *the Word became flesh* into the picture. Since when did an utterance or a message become flesh who then appeared to His disciples, ascended to heaven, seated at the right hand, and will come again in glory...?

Comment: @RevelationLad https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/34570/20832

Comment: Are you simply asking whether the 3 components of the sentence refer to 3 entities (Son, Father, Holy Spirit), or as you asking whether the Trinity (Father, Son, Holy Spirit, consubstantial, and so on) is 'in view'?

Comment: @AnthonyBurg - just the 3 entities, I didn't mean consubstantiality, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Not so fast - it is certainly agreed that water is often used as a metaphor of the Holy Spirit as per John 7:37-39.

However, in the book of Revelation, we have the technical phrase "springs of water" which occurs in Revelation in the following chiastic pattern:

- 7:17 A: The Lamb leads the righteous beside springs of living water
- 8:10 . B: star from heaven falls on the springs of water & embitters
- 14:7 . . C: Worship Him who made…the springs of water
- 16:4 . B: An angel turns the springs of water to blood
- 21:6 A: Thirsty offered drink from the spring of water of life

Notice that the star is parallel to the angel as elsewhere in Revelation.  In Isa 49:10 and John 4:14 the springs of water represent Jesus and His truth of the Gospel of Salvation.  Thus, the plagues in 8:10 (caused by Satan) and 16:4 would represent a counterfeit heresy of false salvation.  This is appropriate since the truth of salvation in Jesus is a sweet truth and the false salvation is a bitter heresy.  This is reinforced in the fifth trumpet where people seek death.  Thus, the middle “C” instance is literal, the “B” occurrence is counterfeit and the “A” is genuine.

Thus, the precedent for the references to the spring of the water of life appears to be John 4:14 and Isa 49:10 -

- John 4:14 - But whoever drinks the water I give him will never thirst. Indeed, the water I give him will become in him a fount of water springing up to eternal life.”
- Isa 49:10 - They will not hunger or thirst, nor will scorching heat or sun beat down on them. For He who has compassion on them will guide them and lead them beside springs of water.

Both these appear to allude to Jesus Himself as the "Good Shepherd" as described in Ps 23 and John 10 as the source of eternal life.

Answer (score 4):

**Is the trinity in view at Revelation 7:17?**

Revelation 7:17 (ESV):

For the Lamb in the midst of the throne will be their shepherd, and he will guide them to springs of living water, and God will wipe away every tear from their eyes.

**Is the trinity in view at Revelation 7:17? The answer is "NO"**

God: is Jehovah.

The Lamb: is Jesus.

**Springs of living water:** Are the provisions made by God for gaining everlasting life, by means of the ransom, God will wipe away every tear from their eyes. Rev. 22:1-2 and 21:4  state the benefits to the obedient human-kind.

Revelation 22:1-2  (NET Bible)

> 22 Then the angel showed me **the river of the water of life—water** as
> clear as crystal—pouring out[c] from the throne of God and of the
> Lamb, 2 flowing down the middle of the city’s  main street. On each
> side of the river is the tree of life producing twelve kinds of fruit,
> yielding its fruit every month of the year. Its leaves are for the
> healing of the nations.

Revelation 21:4  (NET Bible)

> 4 He[a] will wipe away every tear from their eyes, and death will not
> exist any more—or mourning, or crying, or pain, for the former things
> have ceased to exist

Jeremiah 2:13,18 states the unfaithful Israelites committed two bad things. 1/ They rejected me (Jehovah), the fountain of life-giving water and, the God of true guidance and protection, and  2/ they sought protection from Egypt and Assyria. Jeremiah 2:13,18 writes.

Jeremiah 2:13,18  (NET Bible)

> 13 “Do so because my people have committed a double wrong:  They have
> rejected me,  **the fountain of life-giving water,**  and they have dug
> cisterns for themselves,  cracked cisterns that cannot even hold
> water. 18 What good will it do you[i] then[j] to go down to Egypt to
> seek help from the Egyptians?[k]What good will it do you[l] to go over
> to Assyria to seek help from the Assyrians?[m]

Answer (score 4):

> For the **Lamb** which is **in the midst of the throne** shall feed them, and
> shall lead them unto living fountains of waters: and **God** shall wipe
> away all tears from their **eyes**. (Revelation 7:17, KJV)

Notice the similarity with Revelation 5:6, just two chapters earlier.

> And I beheld, and, lo, **in the midst of the throne** and of the four
> beasts, and in the midst of the elders, stood a **Lamb** as it had been
> slain, having `seven horns` and `seven` **eyes**, which are the `seven Spirits`
> of **God** sent forth into all the earth. (Revelation 5:6, KJV)

Are there seven "Gods" because God has "seven spirits"?

Proper hermeneutics requires that we lay aside our biases and preconceptions and understand the *spirit* of what the Bible is saying without reading more into it than what it says.  The Bible is exceedingly clear that there is one, and only one, true God (see Mark 12:32; John 17:3; 1 Cor. 8:6; Deut. 6:4).  The Bible teaches that God is spirit (see John 4:24) and that God was IN Christ (2 Cor. 5:19), the Son of Man.

Neither the word, nor the concept, of "Trinity" is in the Bible.  If one were to read the Bible looking for evidence of multiple God-entities, Revelation 1:4; 3:1; 4:5; and 5:6 all speak of the "seven Spirits" of God.  That's more textual evidence than there is for the supposed Trinity.

*Shall we then believe in a **Septinity?***

**Conclusion**

No, Revelation 7:17 does not address, nor imply, a Trinity. It neither mentions the word, nor makes any clear statement pertaining to three God-entities or beings.

Comment: It's worth noting that in John 7:39, the two instances of "Spirit" were capitalized by Trinitarian-biased translators, not by John's original Greek. Without this added capitalization, there's no reason to ever think it refers to anything that's significantly different from those "Seven Spirits".

Answer (score 2):

Whatever translation you use, and whether 'pneuma' has a capital 'S' or not, and whether springs of living water refer to the Holy Spirit or not, the point of that verse is the location of the Lamb of God. It is because of where he is that he can feed the innumerable great crowd of people, and give them living water.

Where, then, is the Lamb located? ***He is in the centre of the throne of the Almighty - he is in the midst of it***. (That point is also stated in Rev.5:6 & 22:1-3 making a three-fold witness.)

Further, two verses previously we learn that this multitude of people out of all nations and tribes are "before the throne of God, and serve him day and night in his temple, and he that sitteth on the throne shall dwell among them" (verse 15). Does not the Lamb dwell amongst his people, the people of God, and that by the Holy Spirit? Yet the single verse you ask about does not actually make that point, in itself.

There ***is*** clearly a trinitarian link between the Almighty sitting on that throne, and the glorified Son of God (the Lamb) in the centre (midst) of that one throne (for those with eyes to see it). But to find the link between God, Christ and the Holy Spirit in the book of the Revelation, ***other verses need to be invoked.***

Go back to where that one glorious throne is described in chapter four. One aspect of the description is "and there were ***seven lamps of fire burning before the throne, which are the seven spirits of God***" (verse 5). Then, in chapter five, the Lamb makes his first appearance where the description of him includes, "a Lamb as it had been slain, having seven horns and ***seven eyes, which are the seven spirits of God sent forth into all the earth***" (verse 6)

The number seven represents heavenly perfection, so the throne of the Almighty is perfectly guarded by the surrounding seven-fold spirit of God, which also acts as the Lamb's (symbolic) seven eyes. And that is the seven-fold spirit of God now going through the earth since Jesus was gloriously resurrected and made his return to heaven. There you have Revelation's clear connections between the Almighty's throne, and the Lamb's position in the midst of that throne, and the Holy Spirit's guarding and all-seeing aspects in regard to both God and the Lamb.  Nobody can break that triple link.  They can dismiss that link if they like, but the Holy Spirit guards and sees and freely moves. The symbolic aspects of Revelation's descriptions teach as much about the Holy Spirit as it teaches about God and Christ.  But **Rev.7:17 does not have "the trinity in view" as you ask. Read the rest of it for that.**

Answer (score 1):

The word trinity  defines God as being one God existing in three coequal, coeternal, consubstantial persons:God the Father, God the Son (Jesus Christ) and God the Holy Spirit — three distinct persons sharing one essence (from Wikipedia) .  The trinity is not in the bible. Comparing Revelation 7:17 which says, because the Lamb that is in the midst of the throne shall feed them, and shall lead them unto living fountains of waters, and wipe away shall God every tear from their eyes.  There is nothing in this verse that substantiate the trinity according to its definition.

In Revelation 4:8 and 11, creation is attributed to the Almighty God. Jesus never once called himself the Almighty God, Jesus  attributed creation to God, not to himself Mark 13:19 For those days shall be tribulation, such as there hath not been the like from the beginning of the creation which God created until now, and never shall be.

The Lamb in Revelation 5:6 is Jesus who was slain and resurrected. In contrast, God is immortal. Jesus who called himself the faithful and true witness could not be considered truthful if he claimed to be the Creator but is actually not, making his statements in Mark 13:19 ASV, Matthew 19:4 and Mark 10:6 false.  Mark 13 :19 says, For those days shall be tribulation, such as there hath not been the like from the beginning of the creation which God created until now, and never shall be".  Matthew 19:4 ASV  says, And he answered and said, Have ye not read, that he who made them from the beginning made them male and female. Mark 10:6 YLT says, but from the beginning of the creation, a male and a female God did make them.

The Lamb/Jesus has a God as Revelation 3;12 shows. Revelation 3:14 shows that Jesus was created. The same with John 3:16 Jesus was begotten. Revelation 3:14 says, And to the angel of the church in Laodicea write: These things saith the Amen, the faithful and true witness, the beginning of the creation of God. This verse again confirms that Jesus ascribes creation to God not himself. Jesus is dependent on the Father. In John 5:26-27 ASV For as the Father hath life in himself, even so gave he to the Son also to have life in himself and he gave him authority to execute judgment, because he is a son of man. Note that Jesus did not say he has "life in himself". The Father "granted" to the Son to have the same. According to Jesus nothing is essential to the Father. Unlike Jesus, the Father is not dependent on anyone to "grant" him the possesion of life within Himself. Jesus is begotten, The Father is not.

The trinity is not in view in this verse.

Comment: A little Greek idiom and you’d understand that Jesus is claiming to be the almighty. To say that someone is “at the right hand” is to be given the position of authority. It’s not a physical locale. *“If then you have been raised with Christ, seek the things that are above, where Christ is, **seated at the right hand of God**.”
‭‭Col‬ ‭3:1‬* Jesus is seated at the right hand of God in English does not mean the same in Greek, in Greek it means to be given the position of authority or prioritized and it’s not an underling position it’s a superior position which you either have alone or co-share.